# go get not working / go get from a different location

Tags: go

I'm trying to `go get` a project that was initially hosted on a defunct/unavailiable `A.com` server.
The same project is now served under `B.com` but all imports inside the code are pointing to `A.com` (eg. `import A.com/user/projet/lib`).

When I try to `go get B.com/user/projet` it's cloning the git repo from `B.com` but then tries to download resources from `A.com`.

How can tell `go get` that the package `A.com/user/projet` is now served at `B.com/user/projet` (without rewriting imports inside the code) ?

Comment: You can't. You need to rewrite the import statements.

Comment: indeed you have to rewrite the statements there dirty tricks you could do but none are recommended

Comment: @Cerber: the code is already  broken, so forking it to your own repo and rewriting the imports is probably not that unreasonable. Rewriting the imports isn't hard and there are tools to do it a little easier than `sed`. That said, if you don't want to change it, just drop it in a `vendor/` directory and be done with it.

Comment: @JimB I understand that, but since I'm not the maintainer for that code ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another dirty trick no one mentions - manually `git clone`, `git pull` package in $GOPATH/src/A.com/package, before maintainer will rewrite imports himself. `go build`, `go install` work as expected. I do this time to time as quick hack.

Comment: Thanks ! I had to `go get` because It was not pulling it's dependencies correctly (I must have missed something). Yet, it works !

Answer (score 3):

This very hard to do.

As suggested before by myself and @jimb it would be easier to re-write the paths. However there is something you can do.

### When the import path is not a know code hosting site

> The text is the out put of the the command `go help importpath`

If the import path is not a known code hosting site and also lacks a
version control qualifier, the go tool attempts to fetch the import
over https/http and looks for a `<meta>` tag in the document's HTML
`<head>`.

The meta tag has the form:

```
<meta name="go-import" content="import-prefix vcs repo-root">
```

> run `go help importpath` for the full information.

---

#### What all of that means

Basically that means you can import your code base using the old import address but it will clone from the repository provided by the `meta tag`

However you would need the original place to host a page with that `meta tag`.

*Not ideal*

But the Golang team has been know to use that see the below example.

```
$ curl golang.org/x/tools/cmd/rename
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta name="go-import" content="golang.org/x/tools git https://go.googlesource.com/tools">
<meta name="go-source" content="golang.org/x/tools https://github.com/golang/tools/ https://github.com/golang/tools/tree/master{/dir} https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master{/dir}/{file}#L{line}">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/rename">
</head>
<body>
Nothing to see here; <a href="https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/rename">move along</a>.
</body>
</html>
```

> The `go-import` meta tag tells the `go get` where to fetch it from and `go-source` where the source code is to browsing.

Please see below a useful article about this very feature.

[Golang Canonical Import Paths](https://texlution.com/post/golang-canonical-import-paths/)

### Other more questionable tricks

#### Proxying and/or host file entries

Other very dirty tricks would be to proxy the server in question (using something like nginx and host entries) or just use the host file to point the url to the new location but every time you clone you will need to have that host entry.

*Not recommended*

#### Vendor the package and trick go get with git submodules

Another option is to vendor the package in your source repository so `go get` will never attempt to import the package again and it will ignore what ever you have on your `gopath`.

If you add the package to your repository as a submodule to the new location you can still have both code bases separate but because the imported package will be in your vendor folder `go get` will never attempt to import anything.

*In my opinion the lesser then two evils if you can not do the `go get` meta tags*

> I would suggest that you have a look at `git sub-tree` as a alternative to `git sub-modules`. They are pretty cool and easier to deal with.

- For more information on git sub-modules visit: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules
- For more information about git sub-tree's visit: http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/

---

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Dmportella, big thanks for your (long) answer ;). Yet, I'm sorry to say that I had already read `go help importpath` and, as you say, meta redirects are not ideal as ... I'm not the owner of the said "A" server. Rewriting is also not practical since I'm not the owner of the current "B" repo (which means I have to git clone, sed, ...). Building my own repo would mean another package name and would lead to a rename mayhem >:) .

Comment: Yeah i know but there is little you can do other then proxy the domain so it implements the above or you use host name entry to use your server instead. @Cerber I updated my answer to have that but I fear the only way to resolve the issue when you dont have access to the orignal package server is to rewrite it.

Comment: @Cerber i have abridge the answer and given some more thought about vendoring the package but storing in the vendor folder of your repo as a submodule.

Comment: Thanks ! In the end, I dockerized the whole thing so, instead of vendoring it, I placed it in $GOPATH as advized by Uvelichitel. Yet I had to `go get` it so that it fetched it's dependencies correctly